# How can I modify function so I can send parameter without &?

Tags: c, function, pointers

I have implemented function with double pointers, but I'm not sure how change it so I can send parameters without '&'.

```
void load(char* buf_in, char** buf_out)
{
    uint8_t size;

    size = strlen(buf_in) + 1;

    *buf_out = malloc(size);

    if (*buf_out == NULL)
    {
        printf("memory cannot be allocated!\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        memset(*buf_out, 0x00, size);
    }

    memcpy(*buf_out, buf_in, strlen(buf_in));
}


int main()
{
     char* output;

     load("this_is_data", &output);
}
```

Function works properly but I'm stuck with other implementation (maybe there is some simplier way to do it, for example without double pointers?)

Comment: Why do you need to modify this if it works?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using `&`? It sounds like you're unfamiliar with the language you're writing in and arbitrarily trying to make it look like some other language. The fact that you're passing the pointer is not an irrelevant detail to hide; it's critical information to the reader of the program to understand that the called function operates on (and possibly modifies) an object from the caller rather than simply working with a value.

Comment: you cannot. not in plain C

Answer (score 1):

Return the pointer instead of passing the address of a local.

```
char *load(char* buf_in)
{
    ...
    char *buf_out = malloc(size);
    ...
    return buf_out;
}

int main()
{
     char* output = load("this_is_data");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could declare `output` as an array.

```
char* output[1];
load("this_is_data", output);
```